# jointplot not working inside FacetGrid in python seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i'm trying to use `jointplot` in a `FacetGrid` in seaborn but it does not seem to be plotting the data on a grid. the code is:

```
import pandas  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"x": np.random.rand(100),
                        "y": np.random.rand(100)})
df1["row"] = "A"
df1["col"] = "1"
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({"x": np.random.rand(100),
                       "y": np.random.rand(100) + 1})
df2["row"] = "A"
df2["col"] = "2"
df = pandas.concat([df1, df2])
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="row", col="col")
plt.figure()
# this works
#g.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y")
# this doesn't
g.map(sns.jointplot, "x", "y")
```

when i use `g.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y")`, i get the correct result. but with `g.map(sns.jointplot, "x", "y")` it only plots the second data frame and ignores the grid. is it possible to use `sns.jointplot` with data aware grids?

the result i get is:

[image]